# Fetching data from multiple servers with Angular frondend

Tags: angular

We are developing an ERP with multiple back-ends running on various servers, for example, 
hr at abc.com/hr/api
finance at xyz.com/api
and so on

But we have single front-end Angular 6 application, we may be fetching data from various servers at a time.

I am new to Angular, but what little bit I know is we can define variables in environment.ts for either development , production or test server, but what If I bypass enviroment.ts settings with what ever http url I want.
Thanks

Comment: I think you still can use `env` file by making the variables for URLs and use them according to your need inside your service while making API calls.

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik
When I write a service like 
getEmployees(): Observable<any>{
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/employees');
}

I get unknow url error

Comment: Add http:// in front of your fiven url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a pro either in Angular. Have been working on Angular from 6 months now.

So upto my knowledge, the preferred practice is to declare the Base Url in the environment.ts. When you BUILD the angular project it only takes the PROD environment.ts.

Now, coming to your question **"but what If I bypass enviroment.ts settings with what ever http url I want."**
What I understand is
if you don't define the base url in the environment.ts file you'll have to declare it in any of your component, that kind of works but if you someday have to change your Base url you'll have to change the link from each and every component you are using it in. So better stick with environment.ts.

I hope that answers your question rightly.

Comment: Thanks ,but can i define for example 3 variable urls  in PROD environment, so that I can switch to what ever url I want.

Answer (score 2):

Angular should not be concerned where it gets its Data from. You can contact multiple APIs. You dont have to specify the api url youre targeting in the environment (it makes it easier if youre always targeting the same api).

Or you can define multiple Api urls in the environment under different names  e.g. API_URL_HR="" API_URL_FINANCE="".

The Http request needs to get the url from somewhere, but this can be an environment variable or a simple String or a variable.

Comment: Great, I will be happy if can define each nested module having its own environment , and if some module doesnt have its own environment settings, app should get default environment.

Comment: Yes, I am 90% targeting to the URL defined with environments, anyway I found the way to over write or bypass this url by adding 
 http.disableApiPrefix().get('whatever.com');